# How can i use exceptions in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

i am new in spring boot, i following the tuorial from Pluralsight.

i got problem by using exceptions

[image]

here is my service interface

```
package com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.services;

import com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.models.LePille;

import java.util.List;

public interface PilleService {
    List<LePille> listPilles();
    LePille findPille(Integer id);
}
```

here is how i implements the services

```
package com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.services;

import com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.exceptions.PilleException;
import com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.models.LePille;
import com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.repositories.LePilleRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class PilleServiceImpl implements PilleService{

    @Autowired
    private LePilleRepo pilleRepo;

    @Override
    public List<LePille> listPilles() {
        return (List<LePille>) pilleRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public LePille findPille(Integer id) {
        Optional<LePille> optionalLePille = pilleRepo.findById(id);

        if (optionalLePille.isPresent())
            return optionalLePille.get();
        else
            return new PilleException("pille not found");

    }
}
```

[image]
i got red under line to this line :  `return new PilleException("pille not found");`

here is my exception

```
package com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.exceptions;

public class PilleException extends RuntimeException {

    public PilleException (String ex) {super(ex);}
}
```

**EDIT**

i use this code

```
 @Override
    public LePille findPille(Integer id) {
        return pilleRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(()-> new PilleException("pille not found"));
    }
```

it works, why my code doesn't work ?

Comment: As @simon-martinelli wrote,you need to *throw* an Exception. `pilleRepo.findById(id)` method returns `Optional<T>` and its method `orElseThrow` will do following: if Optional has value, return it. If it doesn't, construct exception using passed lambda and then *throw* it.

Comment: Tha anwser of @Marcin Koziarz is right .
()-> new PilleException("pille not found"): This is the lambda expression used as an argument to orElseThrow(...). It creates and throws a custom exception of type PilleException with the message "pille not found".

An equivalence way without without using a lambda expression is:
Optional<Pille> optionalPille = pilleRepo.findById(id);
if (optionalPille.isPresent()) {
    Pille pille = optionalPille.get();
    // Use the 'pille' object as needed
} else {
    throw new PilleException("pille not found");
}

Answer (score 1):

An exception is not returned it is thrown.

```
throw new PilleException("pille not found");
```

Comment: in tutorial it did. @Override
    public Application findApplication(long id) {
        Optional<Application> optionalApplication = applicationRepository.findById(id);

        if(optionalApplication.isPresent())
            return optionalApplication.get();
        else
            throw new ApplicationNotFoundException("Application Not Found");
    }

Comment: Now you changed your code! What do you mean by does not work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: doesn't work meant it not compile, it underline red line

Comment: But your code looks ok. What's the message in the IDE when it doesn't compile?

Comment: i add a new image

Comment: Didn't you read my answer? You cannot return and exception you have to throw it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250899/discussion-between-user609511-and-simon-martinelli).